# how to specify root volume size for ec2 instance in an autoscaling group, started by cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Working with an inherited  aws infrastructure consisting of a load balancer, a DB server, and a few webservers inside an autoscaling group; deployment coordinated by CloudFormation.

Problem is, the spun webservers have a puny root volume (8gb), and sometimes during the webserver lifetime the disk gets filled with logs and temporary files and some services stop working.

I found the part where the machine definition is declared (I think):

```
...
"Properties": {
            "ImageId": {
                "Fn::FindInMap": [
                    "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                    {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    {
                        "Fn::FindInMap": [
                            "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                            {
                                "Ref": "InstanceType"
                            },
                            "Arch"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "InstanceType"
            },
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "KeyName": {
                "Ref": "KeyName"
            },
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
...
```

Instance type is ultimatetly defined somewhere else:

```
"InstanceType": {
  "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "c4.xlarge",
  "AllowedValues": [
    "t1.micro",
    "t2.nano",
     # ... more allowed values
    "cg1.4xlarge"
  ],
  "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
},
```

But I have no clue how to declare the root volume size, nor if it possible at all; and I can't see anywhere an ebs volume being declared.

This is a linux machine, and the root device is /dev/xvda1

```
[ec2-user@ip- /]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.6G  6.2G  21% /
devtmpfs        3.7G   60K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
```

Tried putting this in, right before "UserData":

```
"BlockDeviceMappings" : [
     {
       "DeviceName" : "/dev/xvda1",
          "Ebs" : {
             "VolumeSize" : "20"
           }
     }
 ],
```

But even if I can see that the launch configuration for the machine is updated accordingly (as shown in the screenshot below) CloudFormation wont spin up any new machines after doing that.

[image: screenshot showing disk size of 20gb in AWS console]

Comment: I'm not particularly clear on the behaviour you're expecting here? I'm assuming the Properties section is declared as part of a launch config for the autoscaling group. Are you then expecting CloudFormation to replace all the machines in the ASG with machines with the new 20GB block device launch config?

Comment: @gjtempleton I need the root volume for the spun machine to be bigger than the 8GB that I currently have. The setting above apparently does *something*, because block device is reported to be of the right size; but now the machines do not start. If I remove that BlockDeviceMapping block, it goes back to normal and the machines start normally. Maybe I should work in making my question a bit clearer... :/